# how to get out of a (R) repl’s multi-line (multiple-line) / line-continuation mode

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, ess, r, repl

**My question:  In (an R-repl from ESS layer) in `spacemacs`, I can’t end a multiple-line after I start it**

```
myDf %>%    # here i hit RET
```

so then the REPL goes into multi line mode:

```
+ myDf %>%
myDf %>%
          # REPL echoes nothing, waiting for me to type in anything
sdlfjs    # I type in anything to make it syntax-error and quit, but nothing works
```

• How to end the multi-line input ?   **Ctrl-d does nothing**

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `C-c C-c` or `<ESC>`?

Comment: I just tried it; neither work either, at least for me.  I did find a workaround.. you just have a .R buffer open and send a random line(s) of code into the repl by `C-Ent` ; the REPL will error out... -.-“”””